# nodejs - send multiple files to the client

Tags: node.js, angular, http, file-io, streaming

I need to create nodejs http server and the Angular client.
The server listen to the incoming http request in which clients specify the query parameter

/api/pictures?**query=some query**

Let’s say I have a folder ‘pictures’ that contains:

- pic1.jpg
- pic2.jpg
- pic3.jpg
- instruction.jpg
- manual Instruction.jpg
- …

Whenever the client sends the request with url like:

**/api/pictures?query=pic**

The server should returns files whose names contains the query specified by the client. In this case:

- pic1.jpg
- pic2.jpg
- pic3.jpg

And if the client sends the request with url like:

**/api/pictures?query=instruction**

The server should returns:

- instruction.jpg
- manual Instruction.jpg

**My question is, how to send these files in the most efficient way?**

I was thinking about streaming these files, but it’s rather impossible for the browser client to read the files from such a stream

Or maybe just read all the pictures that matches the criteria to the memory, zip them and then send them.

But I believe there is efficient way to do that, any idea guys? :)

Comment: Could you not just respond with a list of paths for the files that match the query, and then have the client request the images independently?

Comment: For simplicity, I did not write this, but images are stored at the disk (file system) as well as in the database in the binary format (integration with another system). So the solution to send the paths list to the client does not come into play. 

I think the solution of loading the images to the memory and then send the zip to the client is the best solution here

Comment: Or load all found images into memory, open a TCP connection, and send each file separately so that the client can display the images as soon as the first one is received?

But I don't know if the TCP protocol is the right one for sending images

Comment: A general practice would be to generate paths that are handled in the API to serve the images from the database, or to serve static files from disk. Both of those approaches seem to fit your paradigm. If you wanted to bundle images, your responses would be larger and less asynchronous (you need all images to show any), but that could be fine depending on your needs.

Comment: Note that browsers do not support typical `.zip` but rather `gzip`
[This](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) is a good overview